# How do I fix an error where my pyinstaller .exe cannot find the matplotlib file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have python code that uses matplotlib, scipy, datetime, and numpy. I used pyinstaller to create an executable, and when I try to run it it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'". I added all the libraries I need to the .spec file and reran pyinstaller with the new spec file but I still get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running pyinstaller from your virtual environment? Also usually it isn't necessary to add libraries to your .spec file pyinstaller should detect them automatically.

Comment: which version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: You should pass your pyi-makespec command and spec file to find the error.

Comment: @ph140 I have version 3.3.4